# Facebook open graph API custom action privacy

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to change the privacy value of a custom action. In my profile, I am allowing the app to be public, but I want to be able to let the user change this when they perform the custom action. No matter what I pass for privacy, the privacy level of my custom action is always EVERYONE... How do I make the call respect the privacy value I am passing? I understand that I can't make it less private than the users maximum setting, but I should be able to make it more private.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the code you're currently using?